# How can i create a file .csv?

Tags: c, csv

How i can create a file .csv?, i want to create only a file, because i want to declare outside the main() my File. as well i have a functions, and de main() function.

my is this: https://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c i want to write in my file .csv some prints, for example the ip, tcp, etc.

```
#define APP_NAME        "sniffex"
#define APP_DESC        "Sniffer example using libpcap"
#define APP_COPYRIGHT   "Copyright (c) 2005 The Tcpdump Group"
#define APP_DISCLAIMER  "THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY FOR THIS PROGRAM."

#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* default snap length (maximum bytes per packet to capture) */
#define SNAP_LEN 1518

/* ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes [1] */
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6
FILE *f = fopen("test", "w");

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination host address */
        u_char  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source host address */
        u_short ether_type;                     /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};

/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
        u_char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
        u_short ip_len;                 /* total length */
        u_short ip_id;                  /* identification */
        u_short ip_off;                 /* fragment offset field */
        #define IP_RF 0x8000            /* reserved fragment flag */
        #define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
        #define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
        #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff       /* mask for fragmenting bits */
        u_char  ip_ttl;                 /* time to live */
        u_char  ip_p;                   /* protocol */
        u_short ip_sum;                 /* checksum */
        struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
#define IP_HL(ip)               (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)                (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)

/* TCP header */
typedef u_int tcp_seq;

struct sniff_tcp {
        u_short th_sport;               /* source port */
        u_short th_dport;               /* destination port */
        tcp_seq th_seq;                 /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq th_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
        u_char  th_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
#define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
        u_char  th_flags;
        #define TH_FIN  0x01
        #define TH_SYN  0x02
        #define TH_RST  0x04
        #define TH_PUSH 0x08
        #define TH_ACK  0x10
        #define TH_URG  0x20
        #define TH_ECE  0x40
        #define TH_CWR  0x80
        #define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
        u_short th_win;                 /* window */
        u_short th_sum;                 /* checksum */
        u_short th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};

void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);

void
print_payload(const u_char *payload, int len);

void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset);

void
print_app_banner(void);

void
print_app_usage(void);

/*
 * app name/banner
 */
void
print_app_banner(void)
{

    printf("%s - %s\n", APP_NAME, APP_DESC);
    printf("%s\n", APP_COPYRIGHT);
    printf("%s\n", APP_DISCLAIMER);
    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print help text
 */
void
print_app_usage(void)
{

    printf("Usage: %s [interface]\n", APP_NAME);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("    interface    Listen on <interface> for packets.\n");
    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print data in rows of 16 bytes: offset   hex   ascii
 *
 * 00000   47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a   GET / HTTP/1.1..
 */
void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset)
{

    int i;
    int gap;
    const u_char *ch;

    /* offset */
    printf("%05d   ", offset);

    /* hex */
    ch = payload;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", *ch);
        ch++;
        /* print extra space after 8th byte for visual aid */
        if (i == 7)
            printf(" ");
    }
    /* print space to handle line less than 8 bytes */
    if (len < 8)
        printf(" ");

    /* fill hex gap with spaces if not full line */
    if (len < 16) {
        gap = 16 - len;
        for (i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
            printf("   ");
        }
    }
    printf("   ");

    /* ascii (if printable) */
    ch = payload;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isprint(*ch))
            printf("%c", *ch);
        else
            printf(".");
        ch++;
    }

    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print packet payload data (avoid printing binary data)
 */
void
print_payload(const u_char *payload, int len)
{

    int len_rem = len;
    int line_width = 16;            /* number of bytes per line */
    int line_len;
    int offset = 0;                 /* zero-based offset counter */
    const u_char *ch = payload;

    if (len <= 0)
        return;

    /* data fits on one line */
    if (len <= line_width) {
        print_hex_ascii_line(ch, len, offset);
        return;
    }

    /* data spans multiple lines */
    for ( ;; ) {
        /* compute current line length */
        line_len = line_width % len_rem;
        /* print line */
        print_hex_ascii_line(ch, line_len, offset);
        /* compute total remaining */
        len_rem = len_rem - line_len;
        /* shift pointer to remaining bytes to print */
        ch = ch + line_len;
        /* add offset */
        offset = offset + line_width;
        /* check if we have line width chars or less */
        if (len_rem <= line_width) {
            /* print last line and get out */
            print_hex_ascii_line(ch, len_rem, offset);
            break;
        }
    }

return;
}

/*
 * dissect/print packet
 */
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

    static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
    const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_payload;

    printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

    /* define/compute ip header offset */
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    /* print source and destination IP addresses */
    printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));

    /* determine protocol */    
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
    }

    /*
     *  OK, this packet is TCP.
     */

    /* define/compute tcp header offset */
    tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
    if (size_tcp < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
        return;
    }

    printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
    printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport));

    /* define/compute tcp payload (segment) offset */
    payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);

    /* compute tcp payload (segment) size */
    size_payload = ntohs(ip->ip_len) - (size_ip + size_tcp);

    /*
     * Print payload data; it might be binary, so don't just
     * treat it as a string.
     */
    if (size_payload > 0) {
        printf("   Payload (%d bytes):\n", size_payload);
        print_payload(payload, size_payload);
    }

return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *dev = NULL;           /* capture device name */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];      /* error buffer */
    pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */

    char filter_exp[] = "ip";       /* filter expression [3] */
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* compiled filter program (expression) */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */
    int num_packets = 10;           /* number of packets to capture */

    print_app_banner();

    /* check for capture device name on command-line */
    if (argc == 2) {
        dev = argv[1];
    }
    else if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unrecognized command-line options\n\n");
        print_app_usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        /* find a capture device if not specified on command-line */
        dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        if (dev == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n",
                errbuf);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* get network number and mask associated with capture device */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n",
            dev, errbuf);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    /* print capture info */
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    printf("Number of packets: %d\n", num_packets);
    printf("Filter expression: %s\n", filter_exp);

    /* open capture device */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, SNAP_LEN, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
    if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* compile the filter expression */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* apply the compiled filter */
    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* now we can set our callback function */
    pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);

    /* cleanup */
    pcap_freecode(&fp);
    pcap_close(handle);

    printf("\nCapture complete.\n");

return 0;
}
```

but i got this error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
 FILE *f = fopen("test", "w");
```

Comment: Please post your whole source file. I suspect you put `FILE *f = fopen("test", "w");` somewhere it doesn't belong, such as at top-level instead of inside a function.

Comment: its declared together my #defines

Comment: That's wrong, and that's why you get the error. Post your whole source file, so we can tell you where it actually goes.

Comment: ...but please make sure it's a [mcve], that is, runnable but also no unnecessary noise.

Comment: Please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see the actual code and not a filtered description of it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i edited my question, i put my code but now is closed

Comment: That's not helpful. Please read the [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) info. Specifically, the code shown is incomplete.

Comment: In C only variable definitions and initialisation can be outside a function. Function calls cannot be made at a global level and must be done within another function (unlike languages like python).

Comment: @kaylum i need to written a some prints in my .csv file, the prints there are in many functions

Comment: So write a function that opens the file and writes to it. Or open the file in a top level function and pass the file pointer to sub-functions that need to write to it.

Comment: @kaylum but the file will be initializing ? my content will be cleaned many times

Comment: Of course not. It depends how you program it. You can open the file, seek to the end and write every time. Or open the file once and use the same file pointer in many functions which means each write will continue from where the previous write left off. I suggest you go back and look at the I/O chapter of any basic C book or tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write the results in a file, move

```
FILE *f = fopen("test", "w");
```

into your main() function (also check return value since the function can fail), if you want the file format to be csv then you should add the extension .csv so that other people know it has that format e.g. "test.csv" instead of "test". pass the file pointer to all the functions where you need to write to the csv-file.

Now to serialize the contents that you have collected and since the format of a csv-file is row based you need to collect the information before you write it (easier that way). So decide on a structure that will contain all the information you want to put in a row in the csv-file and fill that structure, have a linked list of these structures that you create as you are gathering information, then once you are done collecting, go through the list and write one row to the csv-file per structure.

E.g.

```
typedef struct CsvRow
{
  char ipLocal[32];
  char ipRemote[32];
  ...
  struct csvRow* next;
} Csvrow;

CsvRow* first;
CsvRow* last;

// collecting
CsvRow* newLine =  malloc(sizeof(CsvRow));
newLine->next = NULL;

if (last == NULL) 
{
  first = last = newLine;
}
else
{
  last->next = newLine;
  last = newLine;
}

// then when you are gathering information just add that in last

strcpy(last->ipLocal, "someip");
..

// at the end of your main function do

FILE* fp = fopen("test.csv", "w");
if (fp == NULL)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "file access denied");
  abort();
}
for (CsvRow* p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
{
  fprintf(fp, "%s,%s\n", p->ipLocal, p->ipRemote);
}
fclose(fp);

// free memory
CsvRow* q = first;
while (q != NULL)
{
   CsvRow* next = q->next; 
   free(q);
   q = next;
}
```

Comment: this worked just to one packet, to i get many packets, for example: Packet number 1:
       From: 192.168.1.41
         To: 31.13.67.16
   Protocol: TCP
   Src port: 42980
   Dst port: 443
   Payload (32 bytes):

Packet number 2:
       From: 31.13.67.16
         To: 192.168.1.41
   Protocol: TCP
   Src port: 443
   Dst port: 42980
   Payload (28 bytes):

Packet number 3:
       From: 192.168.1.41
         To: 31.13.67.16
   Protocol: TCP
   Src port: 42980
   Dst port: 443

Comment: since you program seem to do a lot of things I just answered what you asked for, i thought you would "record" information from the network and then once you are done recording, write the csv-file. Maybe you should ask a new question on what you specifically need to get working.

Comment: can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903383/how-can-i-write-many-rows-in-my-file-csv please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the line into opening the file, and declaring the variable, the declaration can stay where it is:

```
FILE *f;
```

The open must occur in your main() function:

```
main() 
{
   f = fopen("test.csv", "w");
   ...
```

Then you can use that in your code anywwhere:

```
 fprintf(f,"some stuff");
```

And remember to close the file when your program finishes (this would be at the end of your main() function...

```
   fclose(f);
```