# How can I save many data in a CSV file?

Tags: c, csv

I have this previous question: [How can I write many rows in my file CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903383/how-can-i-write-many-rows-in-my-file-csv)

In this part:

```
void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset)
{

 int i;
 int gap;
 const u_char *ch;

 /* offset */
    printf("%05d   ", offset); //00000   47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 
    char result50[50];
    sprintf(result50, "%05d", offset);

 strcpy(last->offset, result50);
```

I only can save this section 00000
but I want to save entire, all of numbers, how can I improve my variables?

```
typedef struct CsvRow
{
  char ipLocal[32];
  char offset[32];
  struct csvRow* next;
}Csvrow;
Csvrow* first;
Csvrow* last;
```

I want to save this: `00000   47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a`

Comment: @AndersK can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616296/how-can-i-save-many-data-in-a-csv-file please

Comment: without knowing exactly what you want to save (and in what format), the question is impossible to answer

Comment: CSV files are not limited in size, so as many as you want, presumably.

Comment: You say CSV, but I see the line `printf("%05d   ", offset);` and I wonder if you meant `printf("%05d\t", offset);`. But that would be a TSV (tab-separated file). If you want CSV I would expect to to see you print a `,` somewhere...

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand your question. As the other commentators said there needs to be commas if you storing to a CSV file. Maybe do a function that takes one CsvRow as argument and print that as one line in the file with commas?

Comment: @AndersK in this moment i only can save this part 00000, i want to save all (00000   47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a) in the same cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this ( if I understood correctly )

```
void print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset)
{
  char buf[128];
  sprintf(buf, "%05d", offset );
  char hex[16];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    sprintf(hex, " %02X", payload[i]);
    strcat(buf, hex);
  }
  strncpy(last->offset, buf, sizeof(last->offset));
}
```

although I think your offset[32] is too small to hold all this.

Comment: sometimes i get this kind of  characters: ��"V, why?

Comment: either you have a too small buffer or you have not terminated the string with \0. you could check the length of the string before doing the strncpy `(strlen(buf) <  sizeof(last->offset))` to make sure it is large enough, it needs to hold \0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could either put everything in one `sprintf`

```
int ans = sprintf(result50, "%05d    %02x %02x %02x %02x   %02x %02x %02x %02x", offset, a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7] );
```

Or check the return value from [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) and use another sprintf to the address of buffer start + number of bytes written:

```
int ans = sprintf(result50, "%05d    ", offset);
if (ans<0){
   return -1; //or how you will handle error...
}
ans = sprintf(result50+ans, "%02x %02x %02x %02x   %02x %02x %02x %02x",  a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7] );
```

when your sprintf are working as you like them you should change them to the `snprintf` to avoid buffer overrun errors.